# I want to delete "Mysql2 :: Error :: ConnectionError (Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (0)):"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems

### environment

```
- MacOS Mojave 10.14.6
- Ruby 2.6.4
- Rails 5.2.2
- mysql  Ver 8.0.17 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
- Docker 2.1.0.3
```

### What I want to realize

I want to clear the following error.

```
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError (Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (0)):
```

### Terminal

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.2 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.4-p104), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2019-10-07 22:11:28 +0900

Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError (Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (0)):
...
$ docker-compose ps
      Name                    Command               State           Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rails_test_db_1    docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
rails_test_web_1   bundle exec rails s -p 300 ...   Exit 1
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
volumes:
  db-volume:
```

### database.yml

```
# MySQL. Versions 5.0 and up are supported.
#
# Install the MySQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/old-client.html
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
  host: db

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
  username: app
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: Is `db` container running. Can you add the output of `docker-compose ps` to the question?

Comment: I'm sorry. docker-compose build
is taking time.

Comment: I added docker-compose ps result inside terminal.

Comment: I don't see service with name `db` not running(from docker-compose ps output). That is the reason why your rails application is not able to connect to mysql server at host `db`
Run the service `db` by running `docker-compose up -d db`

Comment: I've discovered if you want to reliably use container names with docker you need a middleman dns server to resolve the host names to docker IPs. There are some scripts and solutions to choose from out there.

Answer (score 4):

That error is telling you that the host `db` is unknown.

You are running `rails s` on your terminal. That is starting your rails server **outside** of docker, therefore the host `db` cannot be resolved. (You only have that kind of DNS resolution for the containers running within the same docker network)

You should just run `docker-compose up` so that **both** services defined in your docker-compose.yml (`web` and `db`) start in the same network (docker-compose takes care of that, you don't need to do any extra setup for it)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I don't need to do any extra setup... OK

Answer (score 0):

You can create a network that will be shared inside your docker between images

```
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.1/16
          gateway: 172.25.0.1
```

Then assign specific IP to your db container:

```
networks:
  my_network:
    ipv4_address: 172.25.0.3
```

After that you need to make sure `db` hostname is linked with db container IP.
The code bellow will add new line `172.25.0.3 db` to you `/etc/hosts` file.

```
extra_hosts:
  - 'db:172.25.0.3'
```

Final version of docker-compose will look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
  extra_hosts:
    - 'db:172.25.0.3'

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.25.0.3

volumes:
  db-volume:

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.1/16
          gateway: 172.25.0.1
```

If you do this you can be sure that `db` host will be always available. I hope that will help you.

Comment: giving static IPs to your containers is a very very bad approach